# EmberJS Refresh page requires user to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, devise

Trying to help out with an Ember app built on rails. When the user refreshes the page the page I lose the session. Chrome Console shows that the local store is cleared thereby eliminating the token.

I am not even sure where to begin in posting code but will gladly post some in response to a request.

Rails 4.1
Devise 3.2.4
Simple_token_authentication 1.2.1
ember-simple-auth 0.4.0

**UPDATE**

If for some reason you need to stay on 0.4.0 you can change your call. Until the patch came out we were doing this:

```
:auth_token => user.authentication_token, :auth_email => user.email, :access_token => user.authentication_token, :token_type => "bearer"
```

Not the most elegant and the only reason we were doing it was because logging out on refresh was annoying the bleep out of us.

Comment: By local store, are you referring to local storage, or Ember Data's store?

Comment: I am referring to local storage

Comment: if I were to guess I'd say somewhere in the code someone is manually calling clear.  http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#Ember-SimpleAuth-Stores-LocalStorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is caused by a [bug in Ember.SimpleAuth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/170). It already has been fix; the fix will be included in the 0.5.0 release which will be released later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you! Once I download and patch I will check this off

Comment: 0.5.0 has just been released: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/releases/tag/0.5.0